# innerHTML of button not logging properly on click event initialized in for loop

Tags: javascript, events

Right now, I have an array of names, I'm assigning each name to a button and I'm setting the button's inner html to the name

```js
var FButton = document.createElement('button')
FButton.innerHTML = Name 

document.getElementById('FBContainer').appendChild(FButton)
```

I am then looping through these "FButtons" then assigning a click event like so:

```js
function AttachListener(){
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#ChatButton")

    for(var button of buttons){
      button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        ChatContainer.style.visibility = "visible";
        
        while(ChatContent.firstChild){
          ChatContent.removeChild(ChatContent.lastChild)
        }

        console.log(button.innerHTML)
      })
    }
  }
```

Now, whenever i console log the button's innerHTML, it always returns the innerHTML of the last 'button' in the 'buttons' array. What might be causing this to happen?

Comment: Use let in the for loop `for(let button ..)`

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` unless you _actually_ need HTML code. Button labels are just text, so you want to both set and log the `.textContent` property, not the `innerHTML` property.

Comment: Ohhhh yes, that makes sense, I forgot the way the variable initializers differ. Thanks for the reminder and help

Comment: does innerHTML return the actual HTML code? I never knew that

Comment: that's the whole reason it exists. `.textContent` is for text, `.innerHTML` is for html markup. As for your question: you're using `document.querySelectorAll("#ChatButton")`, but there is only ever a single element for a any id attribute, so using querySelectorAll doesn't make a lot of sense here. Did you mean `document.querySelectorAll("#FBContainer button")`?

Comment: I've switched to .textContent, that makes alot more sense. The other thing works too, It worked after i changed my var to let. I've multiple buttons with #chatbutton id, so it fetches all of them

Comment: Giving multiple elements the same id not permitted in HTML. If it works it is only because the browser is trying to make sense of invalid markup.